# WordPress date_i18n shows one day earlier

Tags: php, wordpress, date, internationalization

Today I faced a weird issue on `date_i18n` function of WordPress. It's showing one day earlier!

```
$start_date = '2020-04-07';
$end_date = '2020-04-28';
$start_timestamp = strtotime($start_date); // int(1586214000)
$end_timestamp = strtotime($end_date); // int(1588028400)

$i18n_start_date = date_i18n($format, $start_timestamp); // Apr 06 2020
$i18n_end_date = date_i18n($format, $end_timestamp); // Apr 27 2020
```

I checked it on some other websites and it was working fine. Not sure what is creating this issue on this specific website. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem! It was due to daylight saving.

Actually current offset of my timezone with GMT is 0 but at 2020-04-07 (after March 29th) it is 3600 seconds (1 hour) so `date_i18n` function returns **2020-04-06 23:00:00** instead of **2020-04-07 00:00:00**

I was able to fix it by adding offset to the timestamp variables.

```
$start_date = '2020-04-07';
$end_date = '2020-04-28';

$start_timestamp = strtotime($start_date); // int(1586214000)
$end_timestamp = strtotime($end_date); // int(1588028400)

$timezone_GMT = new DateTimeZone("GMT");
$timezone_site = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Dublin');

$dt_now = new DateTime("now", $timezone_GMT);
$dt_start = new DateTime($start_date, $timezone_GMT);
$dt_end = new DateTime($end_date, $timezone_GMT);

$offset_now = $timezone_site->getOffset($dt_now);
$offset_start = $timezone_site->getOffset($dt_start);
$offset_end = $timezone_site->getOffset($dt_end);

if($offset_now != $offset_start)
{
    $diff = $offset_start - $offset_now;
    $start_timestamp += $diff;
}

if($offset_now != $offset_end)
{
    $diff = $offset_end - $offset_now;
    $end_timestamp += $diff;
}

$i18n_start_date = date_i18n($format, $start_timestamp); // Apr 07 2020
$i18n_end_date = date_i18n($format, $end_timestamp); // Apr 28 2020
```

Answer (score 2):

date_i18n retrieves the date in localized format, based on a sum of Unix timestamp and timezone offset in seconds. [date_i18n](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/date_i18n/)

So you're probably having timezone issues.

Comment: Yes It was an issue related to daylight saving! I posted the detailed answer.